# How to successfully run selenium test script in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I've configured my project to run the Build with Jenkins. 
If I execute the testng.xml on my own it successfully executes my test case but if I execute via Jenkins I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ûcp Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: can you please tell us what "Execute Windows batch command" does?

Comment: it does following command Java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml